# Sitecore Rebuild Search Indexes throws UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: lucene.net, sitecore

I'm trying to Rebuild my Search Index in Sitecore 5.3.1 using the Desktop interface. After processing several thousand nodes, I get an UnauthorizedAccessException with the following message:

> RebuildSearchIndex|System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path '...\WebSite\indexes\master\system\deletable' is denied.

Does anyone know how I could resolve this issue?

**UPDATE:** @Divamatrix has the answer, and *all three* steps are required. Giving Full Control to the IIS App Pool identity for the Website and Indexes folders resolved the UnauthorizedAccessException. I got an "unable to rename" error on the deleteable.new file until I gave IUSR read and Write permissions to the Index folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing more of the logs, it's hard to say for sure.. but please check these things.  It sounds like there may be some permissions issues when it gets to trying to create or edit files as it's going through creating the indexes.

1)Please make sure that the app pool identity has full control rights to the website folder.

2)App Pool identity also needs rights to the indexes folder which is usually not in the website folder... its usually in the data folder.  (However, you should also make sure that the app pool identity has full control of the  website folder and its descendants - subfolders and files).

3)Please give READ\WRITE IIS security for  /index folder.

Comment: Exactly right, @divamatrix! The problem cleared up as soon as I had the permissions set properly for the App Pool identity and the IUSR account. Thanks!